# Is Android advertisingId unique per device or per user account?

Tags: android, ios, uniqueidentifier

i tried to find out if the new Advertising Id from Google is unique per device or per google account? In general i would like to know what happens if someone has two devices connected with the same google account?

Same Question for the iOS IDFA.

Thanks in advance
Philipp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AAID is a "device-specific, unique, resettable ID for advertising"
- https://support.google.com/adxbuyer/answer/3221407?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

As I look into developers page, I understand that Ads ID is user-specific unique (so unique per user not per device)

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/id.html

> The advertising ID is a unique but user-resettable string identifier that lets ad networks 
>   and other apps anonymously identify a user. The user's advertising ID is made available to 
>   apps through APIs provided in Google Play services.

Regarding iOS, as I checked reference, this is device-specific unique

> **advertisingIdentifier**
>
> An alphanumeric string unique to each device, used only for serving advertisements. (read-only)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html

Comment: I disagree with Marek. I signed into 3 different devices with the same Google account. The Google Ad ID's were different for each device. If it were purely based on the user (i.e. the Google account), one would expect the ID's to be the same across three devices.

Comment: its unique for device per installation of OS i.e. its reset for the device when OS is reinstalled or user resets it manually. Its is not reset even when you remove all the google accounts from you device and add a new account so its definitely not tied to google account but is tied to device